# Как написать DTD для XML

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

Как написать DTD в DOCTYPE теге который определяет root tag а внутри могут быть любые теги. Для такого XML.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE business PUBLIC "//BusinessData" "business.dtd">
<business>
     <onemoretag attribute="value"/>
     <onemoretag2 attribute="value"/>
     ....
</business>
```

Comment: `<!ELEMENT business (ANY)>`?

Comment: Нет, так он Intellije IDEA подсвтечивает все теги кроме business красным. Ни ваш вариант ни `<!DOCTYPE  business [<!ELEMENT business ANY>]`

Comment: Подсвечивает красным - значит, какая-то ошибка. Какая? | DTD считается устаревшим и опасным форматом. И во многих xml-парсерах по умолчанию отключен. Может, в этом проблема?

Comment: С другими DTD работает нормально, подсвечивает только не валидные теги. если написать `<!ELEMENT business (PICTURE)*>` то PICTURE внтри тега business не подсвечивается красным. А здесь он подсвечивает все внутри тега business. Если к примеру написать `<!ELEMENT busi1111 ANY>` а root tag так же оставить business он подстветит business как не правильный ну и все внутри тоже

Comment: ANY должно быть в скобках: `<!ELEMENT business (ANY)>`. Можно ещё попробовать звёздочку добавить: `(ANY)*`, но не уверен.

Comment: Пробовал и в скобках и со звездочкой. Одинаково

Comment: Какая ошибка? Приведите текст!

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE business>` - в принципе, достаточно этого. Имя корневого тега. Внутри него может быть что угодно.

Comment: Да, знаю, <!DOCTYPE business>  тоже well formatted XML, но мне нужно описать это в DTD. А ошибку которая она дает, `element PICTURE is not allowed`